# Htaccess, allow ip, deny ip and prompt for other

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, apache-2.4

I have a list of ip which doesn't require login prompt ...
I have a list of banned ip ( no prompt juste deny access ) 
But i need a prompt for all others ip ...

I tried this :

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthUserFile .htpasswd
Require valid-user

Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all

Allow from 82.xxx.xxx.xxx

Deny from 109.xxx.xxx.xxx
Deny from 109.xxx.xxx.xxx
Deny from 109.xxx.xxx.xxx

Satisfy any
```

But if you come on with a banned ip, you have the prompt ... 
if you change Satisfy ( "Satisfy all" ) you have the prompt on allowed ip ...

Answer (score 0):

i found a trick for my problem :

```
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all

Deny from 109.xxx.xxx.xxx
Deny from 109.xxx.xxx.xxx
Deny from 109.xxx.xxx.xxx

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    <If "%{REMOTE_ADDR} != '82.xxx.xxx.xxx'">
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "restricted area"
        AuthUserFile /var/www/.htpasswd
        require valid-user
    </If>
</IfModule>
Satisfy All
```

But this solution work only on apache >= 2.4 because IF statement isn't supported by older version ....

do you have any others solutions for apache 2.2  ??